# How use Moles for a constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moles

I have a class like this:

```
public class Product : IProduct
{
    static private string _defaultName = "default";
    private string _name;
    private float _price;
    /// Constructor
    public Product()
    {
        _price = 10.0F;
    }
    public void ModifyPrice(float modifier)
    {
        _price = _price * modifier;
    }
```

I want *ModifyPrice* to do nothing for a specific value, but I also want to call the constructor that set the price to 10. I tried something like this:

```
var fake = new SProduct() { CallBase = true };
var mole = new MProduct(fake)
    {
        ModifyPriceSingle = (actual) =>
        {
            if (actual != 20.0f)
            {
                MolesContext.ExecuteWithoutMoles(() => fake.ModifyPrice(actual));
            }
        }
    };
MProduct.Constructor = (@this) => (@this) = fake;
```

But even if *fake* is well-initialized with the good constructor, I can't assign it to @this. I also try something like

```
MProduct.Constructor = (@this) => { var mole = new MProduct(@this)... };
```

But this time I cannot call my constructor. How am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to mock the constructor, the parameterless constructor of the `Product` class already does what you want.

Add some debugging output to `Product`.

```
public class Product
{
    private float _price;
    public Product()
    {
        _price = 10.0F;
        Debug.WriteLine("Initializing price: {0}", _price);
    }
    public void ModifyPrice(float modifier)
    {
        _price = _price*modifier;
        Debug.WriteLine("New price: {0}", _price);
    }
}
```

Mock only the `ModifyPrice` method.

```
[TestMethod]
[HostType("Moles")]
public void Test1()
{
    // Call a constructor that sets the price to 10.
    var fake = new SProduct { CallBase = true };
    var mole = new MProduct(fake)
    {
        ModifyPriceSingle = actual =>
        {
            if (actual != 20.0f)
            {
                MolesContext.ExecuteWithoutMoles(() => fake.ModifyPrice(actual));
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Skipped setting price.");
            }
        }
    };
    fake.ModifyPrice(20f);
    fake.ModifyPrice(21f);
}
```

See the debug output to confirm everything works as expected:

```
    Initializing price: 10
    Skipped setting price.
    New price: 210
```

By the way, you don't need to use the stub here,

```
var fake = new SProduct { CallBase = true };
```

creating an instance of `Product` will suffice.

```
var fake = new Product();
```

**Update:**
Mocking a single method can be achieved with the `AllInstances` class like this

```
MProduct.Behavior = MoleBehaviors.Fallthrough;
MProduct.AllInstances.ModifyPriceSingle = (p, actual) =>
{
    if (actual != 20.0f)
    {
        MolesContext.ExecuteWithoutMoles(() => p.ModifyPrice(actual));
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Skipped setting price.");
    }
};

// Call the constructor that sets the price to 10.
Product p1 = new Product();
// Skip setting the price.
p1.ModifyPrice(20f);
// Set the price.
p1.ModifyPrice(21f);
```

Comment: Hum, you didn't understand my question. Your example have good points. However, I need a mock of Product which calls original methods, except for ModifyPrice. That why I need a CallBase = true (for a Stub) or an InstanceBehavior = MoleBehaviors.FallThrough (for a Mole). Moreover, and that's the most important point, I want to swamp all future instance of Product with my mock! That's why I need to mock the constructor.

Comment: @Jeco I may have misunderstood you again, but it looks like you could achieve what you want with the `AllInstances` class.

Comment: Still a good answer. I apologize for my incomplete examples, I always have other points in mind. I was comparing several mocking framework to Moles so I tried to study all possibilities. Swamp all future instance of an object with a Moles seems to be a good idea (I tried to check all methods calls and it represented to much 'AllInstances' compared to an 'NonImplementedException'). I was trying desperately to use the constructor to do '@this=aMole'... But as said in Moles manual, it's really an isolation framework and not a mock framework. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

```
MProduct.Behavior = MoleBehaviors.Fallthrough;
```