# Moles to mock an indexed property

Tags: mocking, appsettings, configurationmanager, moles, typemock

I am looking for a way to 'detour' a single item in a configuration file with Moles. I can do this:

```
         NameValueCollection appsettings = new NameValueCollection();
         appSettings.Add("MyKey", "MyValue");
         System.Configuration.Moles.MConfigurationManager.AppSettingsGet = () => this.appSettings;
```

This works fine, however the class which I am trying to test uses some other configuration settings including ConfigSections and the Moles detour seems to have broken this. I only want to replace a specific value, not the whole section. In TypeMock, I could do this:

`Isolate.WhenCalled(() => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyKey"]).WithExactArguments().WillReturn("MyValue");`

When I mock the configurationManager using TypeMock, my test passes, but when I use the Moles version (which looks like it should do the same thing) it fails meaning that Moles must be affecting the ConfigurationManager class in a way which TypeMock doesn't.

Any help on how I can use moles to just behave in the way which TypeMock does would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Moles are you using? Is it v0.94.51023.0 by chance? There are issues with that build and the ConfigurationManager. Have you tried using v0.94.51006.1?

Comment: Thanks Matt, I am indeed using 0.94.51023.0. I have tried to get 51006.1 so I can see if the issue exists in that version, but can't find a download anywhere. I have now managed to narrow my problem down to static constructors. Moles is correctly mocking ConfigurationManager in instance members, but when ConfigurationManager is called from a static constructor, Moles is not mocking it correctly. I have posted a separate thread for this issue at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015173/how-use-moles-for-a-constructor

Answer (score 0):

1. make a copy of current app.settings section:

   ```
   NameValueCollection appSettings = new NameValueCollection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings);
   ```
2. Modify the part you need by calling Set/Add function **(keep in mind that 'Add' function does not overwrite existing values but it adds a new value for the key. On the other hand, 'Set' always creates a new entry and gets rid of the existing values):**

   ```
   appSettings.Set("key name", "new value");
   ```
3. Create the delegate:

   ```
   MConfigurationManager.AppSettingsGet =
     () =>
     {
       return appSettings;
     };
   ```